Pandas new column from groupby averages, but group can't be from complete dataframe
I have a similar problem to this <stackoverflow.com/questions/70824278/pandas-how-to-find-mean-of-a-column-based-on-duplicate-rows-in-another-column> , but my df column that should be used for the groupby has duplicated values that must be treated separately. Here's an example:
   date      x_value
0  29        11
1  29        22
2  29        33
3  30        44
4  30        55
5  30        42
...
17 29        31
18 29        21
19 29        34
20 30        49
21 30        66

I'd like to find a way of doing the average of each separate duplicate group, the result would look like this:
   date      x_value   mean_x
0  29        11        22
1  29        22        22
2  29        33        22
3  30        44        47
4  30        55        47
5  30        42        47
...
17 29        31        28.7
18 29        21        28.7
19 29        34        28.7
20 30        49        57.5
21 30        66        57.5

The df is organized as written above and each group of dates has different sizes (sometimes there are 3 dates on the same duplicate group, sometimes 5, etc.), so I can't just do an average of every 3 rows.
How can I achieve this?

df.groupby(df["date"].ne(df["date"].shift()).cumsum())["x_value"].transform("mean") ?
